# How to call utility functions in SAPUI5 controller

Tags: sapui5

I want to create a custom utility file (JavaScript file) i.e. `/webapp/util/MyUtil.js`

Assuming this is the content of the `MyUtil`:

```js
function myFunc(input) {
    // some code
}
```

And there exist a view and controller i.e. `View1.xml` and `View1.js`. How can I call `myFunct(input)` from `View1.js`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The recommended way is to create a module (similar to class), which can handle your dependencies in the future:

```js
sap.ui.define([], function() {
   "use strict";

   return {
      myFunc: function(input) {
         // some code
      }
   };
});
```

Later, in your controller include this file in the dependencies list and access it through this object:

```js
sap.ui.define([
   "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
   "./MyUtils"
], function(Controller, MyUtils) {
   "use strict";

   return Controller.extend("your.controller.ControllerName", {
      myFunc2: function(input) {
         MyUtils.myFunc(input);
      }
   });
});
```

Make sure that you specify the correct path. If it's controller's folder, you can use the example, otherwise point to the proper folder.

Comment: I have another question, maybe you can help. I have a backend exposed via odata. I am consuming this in Application1 and Application2. When I update my odata model from Application1, the changes are reflected in UI of  Application1 but not in App2 unless i referesh my App2. How can I achieve immediate update in App2 also? Thanks.

Comment: I think it's not possible. In the same application you can attach event handlers to the model's change event, but it's also limited to client side changes. What you want to implement is a server side notification system, which is not a UI5 only task. I would recommend to fetch data automatically, or create a delta service which holds only the changes, and your application can trigger this service automatically using a timer.